# SQLite file's location Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: sqlite, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I'm working with `SQLite` and `Windows 10`.
I followed this video [SQLite Local Database](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/A-Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10/10) (28th minute) to find the package and `.sqlite` file. But when I entered `AppData/Local/Packages`, I didn't find any package has the same name as my project's package's name.
[image: my project's package's name]
[image: No folder has the same name as my project]
Can anyone help me find the package folder of windows 10 app project? Thank a lot!

Comment: Did you build and run (deploy) the project? The package folder is created as soon as the app installs (or runs in debug mode) on your system.

Comment: Yes.. I did... :( But there're no package folder :(

Comment: Did you try to search your file?

Comment: And are you sure that you are copying your database in local storage? because as default databases in your solution ,will not be available in local storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following steps:

1. WIN menu -> all apps -> right click on your app (App1 in your case) -> click uninstall. This will clear the previous app data.
2. In Visual Studio, right click on the project node -> Deploy.
3. Try to find and run your app from the app list to make sure it deployed correctly. then check if you can find the folder. This time you can easily find the folder by sorting on modified date.

If it still doesn't work, see if you can repro the issue with a new blank project.

[**Update**]
If the app locates on phone or phone emulator, Use [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) (works for windows 10) to browse folders. Here is a screenshot for your reference:
[image]

Comment: Hi Alan.. 
Actually, I'm working on Windows Phone 10... and I run the project with Emulator... Any idea to help me? Please..

Comment: Opps... Does it locate on Phone, on the Emulator? Because I build windows phone app?...?? @@
I just want to find the sqlite file..

Comment: If it locates on Phone, where can I find it?